# Can I set a default Calendar reminder time for received invitations?

Tags: microsoft-outlook-365

I regularly miss part of meetings where the meeting organizer set the reminder to 'None'. I have no clue, why Microsoft thinks, that it is a good idea to let the organizer set the reminders for the participants instead of using the user's setting.

However, can I automatically set it to my defaults so that received invitations have the same reminder time as organized ones?

Comment: Totally agree! This is a complete misfeature. My clumsy workaround is to add another appointment at the same time as the newly accepted one and set whatever reminder *I* want.

Answer (score 0):

I would recommend using a third party calendar app which will allow you set reminders for upcoming events, which are independent of the event setting itself.

Also, using another communication tool such as slack has tons of integrations which allow you another medium for calendar reminders to be configured outside the event settings itself.

Regardless of the option you choose I highly recommend setting up a daily message with your entire calendar for the day early in the morning. I find this beginning of day digest along with my custom alerts super helpful for staying on top of meeting schedules.

Comment: This is a company system. I would really appreciate if the answers would stay with the program in question.